# SQL Server: How can I get data from junction table that only has IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, junction-table

I have three tables (examples here).  Two with data and one that is a junction table to handle many:many relationships.

**Users**:

```
ID | UserName
====================
1  | Jeremy Coulson
2  | Someone Else
```

**Repositories**:

```
ID | RepositoryURI
====================
1  | http://something
2  | http://another
```

**RepositoriesUsers**:

```
ID | UserID | RepositoryID
==========================
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 2      | 2
```

So, in this example, user 1 is associated with repository 1. User 2 is associated with repository 2. I need to now search by `Repositories.RepositoryURI` and return `Users.UserName`.

I have this query:

```
select UserName 
from RepositoriesUsers 
join Users on Users.ID = RepositoriesUsers.UserID
join Repositories on Repositories.RepositoryURI = 'http://another';
```

But that returns every row in the `RepositroriesUsers` table.

How can I match data between the junction table with IDs and the other tables with human-friendly text?

Comment: i know you have some good answers below, but it might have made more sense to you, if you started at the table you were filtering on and worked your way down..  `from Repositories r join RepositoriesUsers ru on r.Id = ru.RepositoryID join Users u on ru.UserId = u.Id where r.RepositoryURI = 'http://another`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't actually giving a correct join condition for your second `INNER JOIN`. It should be:

```
SELECT U.UserName 
FROM RepositoriesUsers RU
INNER JOIN Users U 
    ON U.ID = RU.UserID
INNER JOIN Repositories R 
    ON RU.RepositoryID = R.ID
WHERE R.RepositoryURI = 'http://another';
```

Also, you should try to use table aliases in your queries for clarity.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I see what's up now.  I will accept your answer in seven minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple correction is needed to your join:

```
select UserName 
from RepositoriesUsers  
join Users on Users.ID = RepositoriesUsers.UserID
join Repositories on Repositories.ID = RepositoriesUsers.RepositoryID
where Repositories.RepositoryURI = 'http://another';
```

Comment: This is correct but this answer has already been submitted by Lamak.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your join condition for Repositories table and add a WHERE clause as follows

```
select *
from RepositoriesUsers 
join Users on Users.ID = RepositoriesUsers.UserID
join Repositories on Repositories.ID = RepositoriesUsers.RepositoryID
where RepositoryURI = 'http://another'
```

Comment: This is correct but this answer has already been submitted by Lamak.